# Is there a way in pyarrow to query the values of parquet dataset partitions?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

For example, I have a dataset look like this:

```
dataset
    ├── a=1
    │    └── 1.parquet
    ├── a=2
    │    └── 2.parquet
    ├── a=3
         └── 3.parquet
```

and it's loaded in as `dataset = pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset('./dataset')`
How do I query the available entries of partition "`a`" without reading the whole dataset into memory? Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `pieces` attribute of `ParquetDataset`. The `partition_keys` attribute of each `ParquetDatasetPiece` will give you the value of each partition key. If you have ideas about an API to make this simpler, please open a JIRA issue in Apache Arrow.

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1956 about *reading* specific portions of a partitioned dataset.

Comment: Thanks @wes for the help. The information is contained in `pieces` but needs a little bit of digging. I created a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/xujiboy/c3fcc47f720ed9adf2260c5d0ba8aed2) as a convenience method to query the partition value.

Comment: If you'd like to open a JIRA issue about adding help methods to help with this in pyarrow that would be great. thank you

Comment: I just opened one on JIRA [ARROW-3947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3947). Thanks @wes.